# Batch file not running correctly when called from Visual Basics

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am attempting to write code that will call a batch file, wait until it is complete and then move on to the next line of code in Visual Basic. The code I have does open the batch file, however it does not actually execute. It opens the cmd window and displays some non-code I've written, but does not execute. I've tested the batch file by clicking it and running through cmd and it works fine. Just doesn't run through VBS.

```
Dim objShell As Object

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Wait = True
objShell.Run """C:\Users\wjones\Documents\Data Loader\Scheduler\process.bat""", 1, Wait
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
objShell.Run "cmd /c C:\Users\wjones\Documents\Data Loader\Scheduler\process.bat", 1, Wait
```

Comment: For debugging purposes I'd recommend replacing `/c` with `/k`, so that the window remains open after the command completes.